# "Group & resources are not in correct state" error in virtual router

Tags: wifi

When I make wifi hot spot through Virtual router on laptop, Its work fine but when I go through my Desktop it syas "Group & resources are not in correct state". I using n 150 micro adapter in my destop PC. Does Virtual router not support to external wifi adapter. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 9):

1. Open an elevated Command Prompt window
2. Run:

   netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow

Comment: Thanks a lot, this actually solved my problem. This should be the accepted answer.